ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR Al cargar imágenes con AngularJS
Hola cómo están? Quisiera saber cómo puedo solucionar este error net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR,
Esto me está ocurriendo al momento de iniciar sesión en un sistema que estoy desarrollando de forma local, al momento de que los datos que muestra de salida, envían unas imágenes, las cuales se encuentran en la base de datos SQL Server guardadas como Base64.
Lo curioso de esto es que si comento las variables las cuales cargan las imágenes, tanto en el SP como en el BackEnd, obtengo los otros datos sin problemas y el error desaparece, es solo cuando intento traer las imágenes, ocurre este problema con el login, ya que en otro formulario puedo cargar las imágenes sin problemas, a todo esto el FrontEnd lo estoy trabajando con AngularJS y el BackEnd con .NET 8 C#.
Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda, ya que he intentado muchas formas, las cuales son, en la opción de chrome flags deshabilitar el HTTP2 o bien utilizando esto
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Lo cual indicaban en un foro, pero aún así el error persiste.
Esta es la función del Login:
    $scope.login = function () {
        var rutSinFormato = $scope.RUT.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/-/g, '');
        var password = $scope.PASSWORD;

        if (!RutService.validarRut(rutSinFormato)) {
            $scope.message = 'El RUT ingresado no es válido.';
            showAlert();
            return;
        }

        if (!password) {
            $scope.message = 'La clave no puede estar vacía.';
            showAlert();
            return;
        }

        var dv = rutSinFormato.slice(-1);
        var rutSinDv = rutSinFormato.slice(0, -1);
        var rutFormateado = rutSinDv + '-' + dv;

        var requestData = {
            Usuario: rutFormateado,
            Password: password
        };

        $http.post('/Login/LoginUser', requestData)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Inicio de sesión exitoso:', response.data);
                const userData = response.data;                   
                sessionStorage.setItem('LoginResponse', JSON.stringify(userData));

                asignarDatosUsuario(userData);

                window.location.href = 'Login/LoginUsuario';

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error al iniciar sesión:', error.data);
                $scope.message = 'Error al iniciar sesión, por favor verifica tus credenciales.';
                showAlert();
            });
    }; 

Y cuando inicio sesión, llama a esta otra función para cargar los datos de salida.
        function asignarDatosUsuario(userData) {
            $scope.nombreCompleto = userData.nombreUsuario + ' ' + userData.apellidoPaterno + ' ' + userData.apellidoMaterno;
            $scope.correoUsuario = userData.correoUsuario;
            $scope.nombreEntidad = userData.nombreEntidad;
            $scope.rutEntidad = RutService.formatearRut(userData.rutEntidad);
            $scope.ultimaSession = userData.ultimaSession;
            $scope.idPerfil = userData.idPerfil;
            $scope.imgEntidad1 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + userData.imgEntidad1;
            $scope.imgEntidad2 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + userData.imgEntidad2;
            $scope.imgEntidad3 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + userData.imgEntidad3;

        }

Este es el controlador del FrontEnd
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Core;
using ApplicationSUOWeb.Models.Login;
using System.Net;

public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _baseUrl;
    private readonly string _imgUrl;

    public LoginController(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _baseUrl = configuration.GetSection("ApiSettings:BaseUrl").Value;      
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Usuario) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Password))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { Code = "400", Message = "Usuario o Password no pueden estar vacíos" });
        }

        var apiUrl = $"{_baseUrl}/ApplicationSUOWebApi/LoginUsers?usuario={request.Usuario}&password={request.Password}";
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var loginResponseList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<LoginResponse>>(result);
            if (loginResponseList != null && loginResponseList.Count > 0)
            {
                var loginResponse = loginResponseList[0];
                TempData["LoginResponse"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginResponse);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("LoginResponse", JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginResponse));
                return Ok(loginResponse);

            }
            return BadRequest(new { Code = "404", Message = "No se encontró el usuario" });
        }
        else
        {
            var errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Json(new { Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(), Message = errorResponse });
        }
    }

    public IActionResult LoginUsuario()
    {
        if (TempData["LoginResponse"] != null)introducir el código aquí
        {
            var loginResponseJson = TempData["LoginResponse"].ToString();
            var loginResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginResponse>(loginResponseJson);

            return View(loginResponse);
        }

        return View();
    }
}


Donde aparece ese error?? en el back o en el front?

Aparece cuando le doy a inspeccionar el código, en la parte del Front

Prueba lo siguiente, luego de var loginResponse = loginResponseList[0]; agrega loginResponse.imgEntidad1="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" y lo mismo para las otras 2 imágenes. Y luego verifica si aparece el error

Muchas gracias!! Intentaré realizar lo que me indicas…

Agregue lo que me indicas,  desapareció el error y al añadir eso, muestra un punto de color rojo

Al parecer tus imágenes son demasiado grandes, sabes cuanto pesa cada una?. En todo caso, se me hace extraño, porque deberían pesar mucho para que te esté dando ese error (más de 40mb para cada imagen), has cambiado alguna configuración sobre el límite de tamaño para los response?? o algo relacionado con la configuración del timeout?

La verdad no he cambiado configuración del TimeOut y lo raro que desde otro formulario puedo obtener las imágenes, solo en el formulario de login no las puedo cargar

Al ingresar el base64 en una página que las convierte en imagen, el peso de esta es de 0.259 MB

Son pequeñas :(. Se me ocurre es que puede ser algo con las variables de session, quizás estás utilizando cookies cuyo tamaño es reducido. Prueba comentar las líneas TempData["LoginResponse"] y HttpContext.Session.SetString

Al final lo realice de otra manera, y pude cargar las imágenes. Cree un Store Procedure que liste las imágenes por id y que este método a su vez en el FronTEnd sea llamado por otra función la cual envía esta id de las imágenes a dicha función. Muchas por el apoyo!!

La solución a este problema, fue crear otro método el cual obtiene una Id que esta obteniendo desde los datos de salida de la función Login, es decir los datos los cuales carga al momento de iniciar sesión, los estaba obteniendo de esta manera: 

 function asignarDatosUsuario(userData) {
     $scope.nombreCompleto = userData.nombreUsuario + ' ' + userData.apellidoPaterno + ' ' + userData.apellidoMaterno;
     $scope.correoUsuario = userData.correoUsuario;
     $scope.nombreEntidad = userData.nombreEntidad;
     $scope.rutEntidad = RutService.formatearRut(userData.rutEntidad);
     $scope.ultimaSession = userData.ultimaSession;
     $scope.idPerfil = userData.idPerfil;  

     if (userData.idEntidad > 0) {
         const idEntidad = userData.idEntidad;

         $scope.obtenerImages(idEntidad);
     } else {
         alert('No se encontró IdEntidad para el usuario.');
     }
 }

lo cual al momento de obtener el Id le añadí esto:

if (userData.idEntidad > 0) {
         const idEntidad = userData.idEntidad;

         $scope.obtenerImages(idEntidad);
     } else {
         alert('No se encontró IdEntidad para el usuario.');
     }
y una vez que valida el Id > 0, llama a esta función

  $scope.obtenerImages = function (idEntidad) {
      if (!idEntidad) {
          alert('No se ha proporcionado IdEntidad.');
          return;
      }

      $http.get('/ListaImgCarrusel/obtenerImages?IdEntidad=' + idEntidad)
          .then(function (response) {
              console.log("Respuesta de la API:", response.data);

              if (response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
                  var img = response.data[0];
                  $scope.img = {
                      idEntidad: img.idEntidad,
                      imgEntidad1: 'data:image/png;base64,' + img.imgEntidad1,
                      imgEntidad2: 'data:image/png;base64,' + img.imgEntidad2,
                      imgEntidad3: 'data:image/png;base64,' + img.imgEntidad3
                  };
              } else {
                  alert('No se encontró entidad.');
              }
          })          

          .catch(function (error) {
              console.error('Error al obtener imágenes:', error);
              alert('Error al obtener imágenes. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.');
          });

    introducir el código aquí

  };
Lo cual me permitió obtener las imágenes.

